# After rebooting server on C9 my PostgreSQL database is empty

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sqlite, sequel, c9.io

I had a Rails project on C9 with a SQLite 3 database. Recently I wanted to switch to a PostgreSQL database to be able to run a project on Heroku. All records from the SQLite 3 database were copied to the PostgreSQL database with the Sequel gem, without any issues. All records were passed to the new database and I was able to see it, however, after rebooting my C9 project, and starting the PostgreSQL service, and connecting it to my database, I found that there weren't any records inside the database. Or, it's not connected yet. I don't get it.

Every time I reboot the project, records from the PostgreSQL database disappear, I have to create a new database and migrate it again to see my records. What am I doing wrong?

Here is list of my actions:

```
sudo service postgresql start
psql -c "create database myapp_development owner=ubuntu"
sequel -C sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 postgres://ubuntu@""/myapp_development
```

Then update database.yml file records with:

```
Development:
  - adapter: postgresql
  - encoding: SQL_ASCII
  - database: myapp_development
  - pool: 5
  - username: ubuntu
  - password: password
```

Then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

After these actions I can run the project and see my records.

After rebooting the project, I've tried to run the following commands:

```
sudo service postgresql start
psql myapp_development ubuntu
\c
```

but it does not help me to see any records.

Please advise me if I've missed any command.

Comment: By "reboot" do you mean just restarting everything, or does it recreate the VM and set up your code files again? (in which case of course the database is gone)

Comment: Richard, by reboot i mean restarting browser and opening new c9 session with the same workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `psql` as the `postgres` user:

```
sudo sudo -u postgres psql -d myapp_development -U ubuntu -W
```

Comment: Mikhail, i've tried. Received following message: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
Previous connection kept

Comment: Try with -W `sudo sudo -u postgres psql -d myapp_development -U ubuntu -W`

Comment: Mikhail, i've tried – after asking password for user ubuntu result is the same: psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "ubuntu"

Comment: The "peer auth" error will be because you have configured pg_hba.conf to use that rather than password access

Comment: solved my issue by repeating every step from the start and granting access privileges to postgres database. Thanks, guys